# Excluding front_page from is page condition

Tags: frontpage

I am developing this theme, and their are features that I need them in all of the page except for the single and front page. So I've used this conditions

```
If ( is_page() || is_home() ): ?>
//My features here
endif;
```

But I find this code is including the home page, is there any way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( !(is_page() || is_front_page()) ) {
/* These features will not be visible on front page and on single pages. */
}
```

If you want to hide something only on the front page regardless the front page is a static page or list of blog posts then use this code:-

```
 if ( !(is_front_page()) ) {
 /* These features will not be visible on front page. */
 }
```